# How do I change the debug port in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

How to change debug port in Visual Studio 2017? I checked the property pages but to no avail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For me, I was able to find it with the following steps in Visual Studio 2017:

1. Right click on the web project, then click **Properties**.
2. Click on the **Debug** tab.
3. Under the Profile IIS Express, you will find the port at the App URL box.

Comment: Prefer this since you can do it inside visual studio and don't have to hand edit the solution file. Make sure you click create virtual directory.

Comment: This doesn't remove the original virtual directory and names your app [App Name] (1) in IISExpress.

Answer (score 8):

Go into the .sln file and edit the port there.

For example, if it's currently on port: `50722`

Then just do a replace: `50722` replace with: `50723` and it should build just fine. There should be about 5 spots it'll replace.

Answer (score 8):

**Project file properties**

In VS 2017, I was able to update it in the *project* properties, instead of the solution properties.

1. Right-click on your project file, then choose **Properties**.
2. On the **Web** tab find the **Project Url** section. It should say
   something like

   ```
   https://localhost:44348/
   ```
3. Simply modify it to your desired port number and save.