# How can I run an Asp.Net WebApp multiple times in parallel from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-debugging

I am developing a WebServer that runs a Blockchain. So I want to deploy it on multiple Servers and the WebApps should then communicate with each other. 
For Debugging purposes it would be ideal if I could start the WebApp multiple times from Visual Studio on diffrent ports.

I tried using multiple Debug Profiles where I insert diffrent ports as arguments. But the automaticaly opened WebBrowser page still has the default Port and still loads there.

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseSetting("https_port", args[0]);
```

I haven't found any further option or hint on how to archive this. Even though I thought this would be a pretty common occurence.

Comment: Maybe you can get help from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506216/how-do-i-change-the-debug-port-in-visual-studio-2017). We can specify different ports while debugging in VS, but i don't know an option to start a project multiple times.

Comment: I think in visual studio there should be a setting in project settings where you can set startup options. Should be possible to set port there. But I think to attach to multiple stuff from debugger you need something like JetBrains Rider

Answer (score 1):

Open two instances of Visual Studio.  Open the same project in both instances. Set the value of the ports in each instance.  Run them both in Debug mode.